# SwiftUI scaleEffect is not animated within matchedGeometeryEffect

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code results in a proper matchedGeometryEffect for the color of the Square views, but the scaleEffect is not animated.

Is scaleEffect simply not animatable via matchedGeometryEffect? Or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Demo gif]

```
import SwiftUI

struct GeoEffectPractice: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var isSquareAtTop = false
    @State var dragY: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        if isSquareAtTop {
            VStack {
                Square(atTop: isSquareAtTop)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "box", in: namespace)
                    .scaleEffect(0.5)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    isSquareAtTop = false
                } label: {
                    Text("go back down")
                }
            }
        } else {
            Square(atTop: isSquareAtTop)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "box", in: namespace)
                .scaleEffect(1)
                .offset(y: dragY)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        dragY = value.translation.height
                        if dragY < -100 {
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                                isSquareAtTop = true
                                dragY = 0
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        withAnimation {
                            dragY = 0
                        }
                    }))
        }
    }
}

struct Square: View {
    var atTop: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Color(atTop ? .red : .blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

#Preview {
    GeoEffectPractice()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties like `scaleEffect` are only animated when the change is applied to the same `View`. In your case, you have two distinct squares, so there is no animation when you transition from one to the other.

It's also a bit of a surprise that you are seeing the position of the square change smoothly, because you are using `matchedGeometryEffect` without identifying a source. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)), results are undefined if "the number of currently-inserted views in the group with isSource = true is not exactly one". In other words, you are not using `matchedGeometryEffect` correctly.

In your example, it looks like the color change is animated, but in fact I think you are only seeing the blue fade out and the red fade in. There is no true animation from blue to red, for the same reason as the scale effect is not animated (it's not the same `Square`).

To get it working as you expect, you need to apply the changes to the same `Square`. A revised version of `GeoEffectPractice` is shown below. Things to notice:

- There is only one `Square`, which is shown in an overlay.
- `matchedGeometryEffect` is not needed at all.
- The drag gesture is more or less the same as you had it before (but some redundancy removed).
- The color change is now animated, as a bonus :)

```swift
struct GeoEffectPractice: View {
    @State var isSquareAtTop = false
    @State var dragY: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if isSquareAtTop {
                Button {
                    isSquareAtTop = false
                } label: {
                    Text("go back down")
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: isSquareAtTop ? .top : .center) {
            Square(atTop: isSquareAtTop)
                .scaleEffect(isSquareAtTop ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                .offset(y: isSquareAtTop ? 0 : dragY)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        dragY = value.translation.height
                        if dragY < -100 {
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                                isSquareAtTop = true
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        dragY = 0
                    })
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, the docs say results are undefined if "the number of currently-inserted views in the group with isSource = true is not exactly one." But in the question's code example, because the if/else condition is used, there is only one currently inserted Square at any given time, no? Since there's only one Square at any given time, there can only be one Square which has isSource = true. So my understanding is that isSource = true shouldn't be necessary for that reason.

Comment: @Plato Well to keep it clean, you could add ```isSource: isSquareAtTop``` to the first case and ```isSource: !isSquareAtTop``` to the second case. This behaves the same as your original version so you might be right about the implicit definition. But it won't help with the scaling issue, you need to apply the scaling change to a single Square for the animation to work. This obsoletes the need for using matchedGeometryEffect at all.